# Bing Maps REST Toolkit - accessing RESPONSE object

Tags: rest, bing-maps

I'm unable to actually access the member(s) in this undocumented class: **BingMapsRESTToolkit.Response**

Code in various places (e.g.)[Bing Maps REST Services Toolkit - Access Value Outside of Delegate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55186050/bing-maps-rest-services-toolkit-access-value-outside-of-delegate) seem to copy the non-working example from MSDN.

For example, this method has no access to the array of Snapped coordinates contained in the Response object.  The line where rez is assigned to the cast of the response gives us a null.

```
private List<Coordinate> MapSnaps(List<Coordinate> coordinates)
{
    // Build our request object
    var req = new SnapToRoadRequest();
    req.BingMapsKey = _sessionKey;
    req.UserRegion = "US";
    req.SpeedUnit = SpeedUnitType.MPH;
    req.TravelMode = TravelModeType.Driving;
    req.Points = coordinates;
    var response = req.Execute().GetAwaiter().GetResult();

    if(response != null &&
       response.ResourceSets != null &&
       response.ResourceSets.Length > 0 &&
       response.ResourceSets[0].Resources != null &&
       response.ResourceSets[0].Resources.Length > 0)
    {
        // rez gets nothing, results in null because the two objects are nothing alike
        var rez = response.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0] as BingMapsRESTToolkit.Location;

        // Snaps has 69 SnappedPoint items, but the member as shown in the debug window
        // SnappedPoints under snaps cant be accessed in code - just in debugger
        var snaps = response.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0]; // 

        Console.WriteLine("-.-"); // <-- breakpoint here

    }

    // TODO: Once we get this response snafu sorted, convert and return
    // matching list of road-snapped coordinates to caller...

    return ConvertToCoords(response);
}
```

When I  debug using Visual Studio 2019, it clearly shows that there are 69 'SnappedPoint' values waiting to be used in  response.ResourceSet[0].Resources[0] -- but I cant get to them. Here is what the debugger shows:

**snaps**               BingMapsRESTToolkit.SnappedPoint[69]

```
SnappedPoints   BingMapsRESTToolkit.SnappedPoint[69]
BoundingBox     null
Type            null

Each member of the SnappedPoints array contains:

    Coordinate          {Lat:double, Lon:double}
    Index               int
    Name                String for name of road
    SpeedLimit          double?
    TruckSpeedLimit     double?
```

Trying: snaps.SnappedPoints[x] does not work as the member does not exist. BoundingBox and Type both are accessible and are set to null, but there's no way I see to access the contents of SnappedPoints. There's no intellisense and manually typing the member name only results in errors.

WTH am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the solution is fairly straight-forward, but at least for me, isn't inferred in the (lack of) documentation for the BingMapsRESTToolkit project.

The Response object can take on a variety of object types depending on the initial request.

In order to get access to the SnappedPoints array, the Response has to be cast as a SnapToRoadResponse type, such like:

```
var snaps = response.ResourceSets[0].Resources[0] as SnapToRoadResponse;
```

Which is kind of ugly, but it does work.